# XML Parsing - Missing nodes

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom

I am running into the issue that some nodes of my xml file are parsed & displayed correctly while others aren't detected (at least I don't know what's going wrong here)

Rather than posting the xml file I will provide a [link to it](http://inexus.us/compare.xml). Here's a small XML snippet for you to review the xml structure:

```
<offers version="1"><group name="games">
    <o id="1" url="http://inexus.us/world-of-warcraft-eu/pre-paid-game-time-card-60-days" price="21.53" avail="1">
        <name>World of Warcraft EU Pre-Paid Game Time Card 60 Days</name>
        <currency>
            EUR
        </currency>
    </o>
```

Now, I am using this code to parse/read the xml file.

```
$xmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDOM->load("http://inexus.us/compare.xml");
$document = $xmlDOM->documentElement;
foreach ($document->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $temp) {
            echo $temp->nodeName."=".$temp->nodeValue."<br />";

        }
    }
}
```

Using that code I am getting the `name` of each elemet `o`
However I also need to get the information stored inside the `o` element... (i.e. `id`, `url`, `price`) but I don't quite understand how I can access them.

Also the output returns several `#text=` blocks. (I guess this happens because of whitespaces in the xml?)

A small snippet of the Output:

```
#text=
#text=
o= World of Warcraft EU Pre-Paid Game Time Card 60 Days EUR
#text=
o= World of Warcraft EU Battle Chest cd-key EUR
#text=
o= World of Warcraft EU Cataclysm cd-key EUR
#text=
```

Any help/hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such an XML document, it's most often more easy to deal with it in [*SimpleXML*](http://php.net/SimpleXML). Generally what you're looking for is called *attributes*. Next to  *text* values which are children of *elements*, *elements* also have *attributes*.

In *SimpleXML* the access is rather straight forward: Accessing *attributes* of an *element* is with the array notation and a string-key:

```
$game['id']; # id attribute of $game (here the <o> element)
```

To access a children (and often there is only one children, like the `<name>`), you access it via it's child-element-name:

```
$game->name; # (first) name child element of $game
```

And if you use it in string contexts (e.g. as string parameter; `echo` or casting `(string) $game->name`) it will return not the element but it's inner text-value.

Here is some example code (which also uses a simple [`xpath`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath)):

```
$url = 'http://inexus.us/compare.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->xpath('/*/group/o') as $index => $game)
{
    printf("[%04d] %' -48s  %' 5s %s\n       <%s>\n",
        $game['id'],            # id attribute
        trim($game->name),      # name child text value
        $game['price'],         # price attribute
        trim($game->currency),  # currency child text value
        $game['url']            # url attribute
    );
}
```

And this is the output:

```
[0001] World of Warcraft EU Pre-Paid Game Time Card 60 Days  21.43 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/world-of-warcraft-eu/pre-paid-game-time-card-60-days>
[0003] World of Warcraft EU Battle Chest cd-key          10.31 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/world-of-warcraft-eu/battle-chest-cd-key>
[0668] World of Warcraft EU Cataclysm cd-key              6.18 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/world-of-warcraft-eu/cataclysm-cd-key>
[0954] World of Warcraft EU Mists of Pandaria cd-key     18.80 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/world-of-warcraft-eu/mists-of-pandaria-cd-key>
[0988] World of Warcraft EU Battle Chest + Cataclysm cd-key  15.48 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/world-of-warcraft-eu/battle-chest-cataclysm-cd-key>
[0018] Eve Online Pre-Paid Card 60 Days Special Edition  28.40 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/eve-online/pre-paid-card-60-days-special-edition>
[0766] Eve Online +30 Days cd-key                        11.60 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/eve-online/30-days-cd-key>
[1057] Eve Online Pre-Paid Card 60 Days                  25.82 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/eve-online/pre-paid-card-60-days>
[0029] Sony Online Pre-Paid 30 days EU                   14.19 EUR
       <http://inexus.us/sony-online/pre-paid-30-days-eu>
...
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OHVKmo)

Comment: Thank you very much! You went ahead and showed me an even more advanced/organized way to deal with the xml input! Now I just need to figure out how I can mark 2 Answers as the correct ones! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `#text` has to deal with the whitespace. You can use `preserveWhiteSpace = false` (see below), but you must remember to use this before you `load()`.

As for the attributes, you can use the `hasAttributes()` to check the node has attributes then iterate through the node's attributes using `attributes`.

In the example below i took a shortcut and grabbed all of the `o` tags:

```
<?php
$xmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDOM->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmlDOM->load("http://inexus.us/compare.xml");
$offers = $xmlDOM->getElementsByTagName('o');
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    if($offer->hasAttributes()){
        foreach($offer->attributes as $attr){
            $name = $attr->nodeName;
            $value = $attr->nodeValue;
            echo $name.' = '.$value.'<br>';
        }
    }
    if ($offer->hasChildNodes()) {

        foreach($offer->childNodes as $o) {
            echo $o->nodeName."=".$o->nodeValue."<br />";

        }
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me the solution, now I can already concentrate on the next step! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Check [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) for a full list of properties you can access in a `DOMNode`. For your questions:

1. Check the [`attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) property of `$temp` to have access to all its attributes. It's a [`DOMNamedNodeMap`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php), so you can access them (for instance) like:

   ```
   foreach ($temp->attributes as $name => $attrNode) {
       echo $name."=".$attrNode."<br />";
   }
   ```
2. You can eliminate the unwanted `Text` nodes by testing the [`nodeType`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype) against [`XML_ELEMENT_NODE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.constants.php) before including it in the results.